# Get the most up-voted questions in the last 24h filtered by my "favorite tags" selections

Tags: support, search

I've selected around 25 favorite tags on Stack Overflow. I would like to get a list of the most up-voted questions, sorted by the number of up-votes, that have been submitted in the last 24 hours and that contain one or more of my favorite tags.

Does Stack Overflow offer this functionality?

Why I want this: I'm running a digest (about web development) and I would like to include interesting questions in this digest. My job is very time consuming, so I don't have much time to search for interesting content on Stack Overflow. A "top questions in the last 24h" would help me out here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, actually, although you'll have to be a bit deliberate about defining the timeframe.

You can combine the `intags:mine`, `is:question`, and `created:<date>` operators along with a sort by votes to [produce the relevant list of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=intags%3amine%20created%3a2013-10-01%20is%3aquestion). The caveat is that you'd have to adjust the date each day, and the time frame is date-based instead of timeframe-based*, but it should work generally well for the purposes you're describing.

<sub>*This might make an interesting feature request, to allow a negative value in the form of "hours ago"</sub>

Comment: I've created a bookmarklet for this: http://codepen.io/simevidas/pen/BlJKq (By default, the `created:` value is computed to yesterday's date)